# Request headers is not going along with request in retrofit 2.6.0 android kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, request-headers

I am trying to call an API through our app with an authorization token. I have tried all available solutions with no luck.

Here is my retrofit client with okhttp

```
companion object {
        var token: String = "token"
        var apiService: ApiService? = null

        fun getInstance(): ApiService {

            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(Interceptor(token))
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS))

            if (apiService == null) {

                apiService = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build().create(ApiService::class.java)
            }
            return apiService!!
        }
    }
```

Interceptor

```
class Interceptor(
    private val token: String
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        request = request.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Api Call

```
// get all users
    @GET("api/user/get_all_users.php")
    suspend fun getSpaces(
    ): Response<UserListResponse>
```

I tried sending a dynamic header as

```
// get all users
    @GET("api/user/get_all_users.php")
    suspend fun getSpaces(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String = "Bearer 2|ec131b10fb15295445e8075dfa8883b5"
    ): Response<UserListResponse>
```

I tried sending a hardcoded header as

```
// get all users
    @Headers("Authorization: Bearer 2|ec131b10fb15295445e8075dfa8883b5")
    @GET("api/user/get_all_users.php")
    suspend fun getSpaces(): Response<UserListResponse>
```

And, Also tried with the interceptor. I don't know where I am doing a mistake.

Here is the header logging of the request

```
2022-05-21 01:39:24.839 30140-30140/com.test.myapp D/Called: 0
2022-05-21 01:39:25.091 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://test_domain.com/test/api/user/get_all_users.php
2022-05-21 01:39:25.091 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Authorization: Bearer 2|ec131b10fb15295445e8075dfa8883b5
2022-05-21 01:39:25.092 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Accept: application/json
2022-05-21 01:39:25.092 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json
2022-05-21 01:39:25.092 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
2022-05-21 01:39:25.436 30140-30140/com.test.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2022-05-21 01:39:25.438 30140-30417/com.test.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=871ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=197729743820535, Vsync=197729777153869, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=197729789299244, AnimationStart=197729789306552, PerformTraversalsStart=197730340706860, DrawStart=197730341252552, SyncQueued=197730612659168, SyncStart=197730612991321, IssueDrawCommandsStart=197730613160552, SwapBuffers=197730614595937, FrameCompleted=197730616140629, DequeueBufferDuration=220769, QueueBufferDuration=467692, GpuCompleted=0, 
2022-05-21 01:39:25.821 30140-30140/com.test.myapp D/Called: 0
2022-05-21 01:39:25.827 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://test_domain.com/test/api/user/get_all_users.php
2022-05-21 01:39:25.827 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Authorization: Bearer 2|ec131b10fb15295445e8075dfa8883b5
2022-05-21 01:39:25.827 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Accept: application/json
2022-05-21 01:39:25.828 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json
2022-05-21 01:39:25.828 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
2022-05-21 01:39:25.862 30140-30567/com.test.myapp D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.test.myapp :443 
2022-05-21 01:39:25.862 30140-30570/com.test.myapp D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.test.myapp :443 
2022-05-21 01:39:27.038 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://test_domain.com/test/api/user/get_all_users.php (1210ms)
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://test_domain.com/test/api/user/get_all_users.php (1945ms)
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Fri, 20 May 2022 20:09:28 GMT
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Fri, 20 May 2022 20:09:28 GMT
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: awex
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: awex
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-content-type-options: nosniff
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-request-id: 453cf99926f1552c1bdb630482505474
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-request-id: 5e903f039cec6ceacf28bc3209a19462
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30570/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP
2022-05-21 01:39:27.039 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP
2022-05-21 01:39:27.062 30140-30140/com.test.myapp D/Response: UserListResponse(data=null, message=Unauthorized access denied!, status=failure, statusCode=401)
2022-05-21 01:39:27.063 30140-30140/com.test.myapp D/Response: UserListResponse(data=null, message=Unauthorized access denied!, status=failure, statusCode=401)
```

Adding response of my postman request which is working fine
[image: Postman Response]

Comment: `2022-05-21 01:39:25.091 30140-30567/com.test.myapp I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Authorization: Bearer 2|ec131b10fb15295445e8075dfa8883b5` your request header is going fine, something else is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Praveen, In last call there is no Authorization header. I'm trying to understand, why there is multiple call? Non Authorization request is working fine. Is it due to interceptor?

Comment: Have you tried making request on Postman?

Comment: Yes, Working fine on postman.

Answer (score 0):

**It wasn't an implementation problem of retrofit. It was a typo problem in our backend APIs.**

I was using a self-written API library using PHP and implemented the authorization to prevent unauthorized API calls. In the implementation of authorization, I forget to deal with the case sensitivity of authorization header coming in request headers. In the case of retrofit, the Key for the authorization header is **Authorization** whereas in the case of postman it was **authorization**.